# some arguments not work from AppleScript to grep thru do shell script

Tags: bash, macos, applescript

in applescript editor:

```
do shell script "grep -w 'SomeText' /tmp/test"
```

ignores -w

in Bash:

```
grep -w 'SomeText' /tmp/test
```

not ignores arguments

But for example arguments -v (negative) works in AppleScript with do shell script

it is happening on both different computers with different systems

how i can use -w argument in grep from applescript?

Thanks!

Comment: Running `grep -w 'SomeText' /tmp/test` in Terminal on my system just returns `grep: /tmp/test: No such file or directory` and therefore providing a nonworking example is about worthless. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit you question to conform to it.

Comment: @user3439894 I don't think asking you to create `/tmp/test` yourself is too much to ask.

Comment: @chepner, IMO When someone says something works one way but not the other and does so without providing actual working details then they need to provide a MCVE. That's what it's there for!

Comment: @chepner, I think you're missing the point regarding my first comment. I certainly have no issue with having to create a file and some content to work with to test against an issue presented. However, there really was no issue presented! **Only a statement that _x_ works differently in _y_ then _z_, but showed absolutely no proof whatsoever to any factuality of said statement!** So, how can/should a question that lacks the pertinent details to solve an unproven issue be answered? One way of course is to prove that _x_ works the same in _y_ and _z_, and so that's how I've answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of where I run the `grep -w ...` *command* from, **Terminal** or **ApplesScript's** `do shell script` command, I get identical *output*.

The manual page for the `-w` *option* in `grep` states the following:

> **−w, −−word-regexp**
>               The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by ‘[[:<:]]’ and ‘[[:>:]]’; see
>             re_format(7)).

The manual page for `re_format` states:

> There are two special cases‡ of bracket expressions: the bracket expressions [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] match the null string at the beginning and end of a word respectively. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters which is neither preceded nor followed by word characters. A word character is an *alnum* character (as defined by ctype(3)) or an underscore.

## In Terminal:

- **Contents of `/tmp/test`:**

  ```
  $ cat /tmp/test
  SomeText
  MoreText
  ASomeTextZ
  Other Text
  0 SomeText 1
  $
  ```
- **Using `grep` *without* `-w` on `/tmp/test`:**

  ```
  $ grep 'SomeText' /tmp/test
  SomeText
  ASomeTextZ
  0 SomeText 1
  $
  ```

  - As it should, `grep` finds all three lines containing `'SomeText'`.
- **Using `grep` *with* `-w` on `/tmp/test`:**

  ```
  $ grep -w 'SomeText' /tmp/test
  SomeText
  0 SomeText 1
  $
  ```

  - As it should, `grep -w` finds only the lines conforming to what's stated in the manual page excerpts shown above. In this case, only two of the three lines that contain `'SomeText'`.

The *output* of each `grep` *command*, show above, when wrapped in a `do shell script` *command* in **AppleScript** are identical, as should be.

## In Script Editor:

[image: Insert Image Here]

---

Because these are the expected results is why I'm adamant about following [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), when asking questions such that you have, in the manner you have!

I'd suggest you show us the actual *content* of your `/tmp/test` *file* and the actual *output* you get from each of the `grep` *commands*, with and without the `-w` *option*, from both **Terminal** and **AppleScript's** `do shell script` *command*.

Although it shouldn't make a difference, nonetheless you should also provide macOS version info so we can test this under the actual version of macOS you're using, so as to see if that's a relevant factor in the equation.